# Get complete Route of Nested UL/LI and Validate

Tags: jquery

I have this [UL/LI](http://jsfiddle.net/q6yDe/585/).

Users will choose them from a menu and what I need to achieve is to get a text line of the entire route. For example `First Level 2 - Second Level 1 - Third Level 1`.
And, at the same time I'd like to validate that there's no more options on the right side.
For example if users click `First Level 2 - Second Level 1` I'd like to do something in order to let him know that there are more choices after `FL2 - SL1` (a bool variable with true or false will do the work, I can take it from there with some warning)

I've played with the text attribute but it's not working since the menu is nested and not in a single-level UL.

Any idea would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of li's click event i have used anchor tag click event to get the route and checking any further  levels are present

http://jsfiddle.net/q6yDe/586/

Comment: Thanks, nice solution, now I can move forward! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at a solution can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/KVs9C/.

```
$("#mylist a").click(function() {
    var path = "",
        moreChoices = $(this).next().size(); 

    console.log("More choices? " + !!moreChoices);

    $(this).parents("li").each(function() {
        path = $(this).find("a:first").text() + " - " + path;
    });
    console.log(path);
});
```

Like fuzionpro, I suggest that you add the click-listener to the anchor-elements instead of the li-elements. The path can be constructed by traversing all parent li elements, and appending the text of the first anchor tag in each. The path currently ends with a surplus dash, which should be removed.